# how to make sure to get the latest values of input when using useState hook in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Below is a React component that uses `useState` hook but I do not get the latest values.

```
import { FC, useRef,useState } from "react";
import { Album } from "../../../types/album";
import "./album.module.css";

interface Props {
 addAlbum(newAlbum: Album): void;  
}

const NewAlbum: FC<Props> = (props) => {
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [releaseDate, setReleaseDate] = useState('');

console.info("New Album Component Render");

const releaseDateRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
const albumNameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

const addAlbumHandler = () => {
  setName(albumNameRef.current?.value!)
  setReleaseDate(releaseDateRef.current?.value!)


 // *LOC
  props.addAlbum({
   name: name,
   releaseDate: releaseDate
   id: Math.random().toString(),
 });
};

return (
<>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Album Name" ref={albumNameRef} />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Release year" ref={releaseDateRef} />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onClick={addAlbumHandler}>
      Add New Album
    </button>
  </div>
</>
)};

export default NewAlbum;
```

When I click the AddNewAlbum button, `addAlbumHandler()` gets called however, I don't get the latest value of the `name` & `releaseDate`.

However, when I update the code at *LOC as below

```
 props.addAlbum({
  name: albumNameRef.current?.value!,
  releaseDate: releaseDateRef.current?.value!,
  id: Math.random().toString(),
});
```

I do get the desired values,

I understand that `useState` hook behind the scenes does not execute immediately

How to make sure to get the latest values of input when using useState hook in React?

Comment: Why are you saving the values in state if you don’t need to?

Comment: @JBallin Sorry for the typo

Comment: Why are you using a ref instead of just updating state onChange in the input? Then your submit handler could just read from state.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

1. You should never have to use `useRef` to retrieve values from elements. This is totally unreactly and totally unnecessary. The usual react way to do this is to define state, which is used as values for inputs and provide appropriate value change handlers to the inputs which alter the state.
2. As you know yourself, state changes do not happen immediately. This is the only reason your first example does not work and also explains why the second one does.

A recommendation for code that should work:

```
import { FC, useRef,useState } from "react";
import { Album } from "../../../types/album";
import "./album.module.css";

interface Props {
  addAlbum(newAlbum: Album): void;  
}

const NewAlbum: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [releaseDate, setReleaseDate] = useState('');

  const nameChangeHandler = (e) => setName(e.target.value);
  const releaseDateChangeHandler = (e) => setReleaseDate(e.target.value);

  console.info("New Album Component Render");

  const addAlbumHandler = (e) => {    
    // *LOC
    props.addAlbum({
      name: name,
      releaseDate: releaseDate
      id: Math.random().toString(),
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Album Name"
          value={name}
          onChange={nameChangeHandler}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Release year"
          value={releaseDate}
          onChange={releaseDateChangeHandler}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={addAlbumHandler}>
          Add New Album
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default NewAlbum;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is also a way. But may I ask you to put some light/details on why `useRef` should be avoided? Thanks!

Comment: I think the official documents about [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) should best answer your question. One article also references [an article with a nice comparison between the two](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/).